# Map with custom objects

Tags: swift

I have some objects

```
let one = Person(name: "Joe", age:20)
let two = Person(name: "Phil", age:21)
let three = Person(name: "Moe", age:21)
```

then I have an array

```
let array = [one, two, three]
```

now I need to create a new array, that will contain only persons whose age is 21.

I try

```
var newArray : [Person] = array.map ({ $0.age = 21 })
```

but compiler says that he can't convert result type '_?' to expected type [Person]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
var newArray : [Person] = array.filter {$0.age == 21}
```

`map` just modifies your array. it doesn't remove elements.

Answer (score 4):

Map is not what your are expecting to do. Map creates a new array from the array.

```
let one = Person(name: "Joe", age:20)
let two = Person(name: "Phil", age:21)
let three = Person(name: "Moe", age:21)

let array = [one, two, three]
var newArray : [Int] = array.map ({ $0.age })
```

Returns a new array, containing age of all people.  [20, 21, 21]

I think you are probably after **filter** method,

```
var newArray : [Person] = array.filter ({ $0.age == 21 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `map` and `filter` functions:

```
var newArray : [Person] = array.filter ({ $0.age == 21 })
```

Also note `==` instead of `=`.

`filter` is used to take some items from your original array.

`map` is used to transform all the items from your original array to new items.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is for converting your array of elementA to array of elementB. The code inside the closure must return the result of transformation (for each element).

Maybe you want a `filter` as answered above. You must use equal compare (`==`, but not `=`)

```
var newArray : [Person] = array.filter {$0.age == 21}
```